# Posting With AJAX not working, Can't get $_POST value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I'm having a little issue. I am working on a site and this is the first I have used ajax to post to to a page. I have a form with a submit button and a link on it. When the submit button is pressed everything works but users should be able to click the link to by pass a page but I still need some information posted to that page so I googled ho to post with out a submit button and ajax came up so I figured I'd give it a shot. It seems to not be working. Here is the code that I am using.

```
 $('#chkEndAccDate').click(function(evt){
    alert("before ajax");
    var totalcost = $('#total_cost').val();
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "http://sandbox.phareconsulting.com/complete_order.php",
    `enter code here`data: {cost : totalCost}
       });
   alert("after ajax");
});
```

This code also doesn't work when i try it
    $(document).on('click','#chkEndAccDate',function(){
      cost = $('#total_cost').val(); 
       $.post("http://www.sandbox.phareconsulting.com/complete_order.php",
      {cost: cost},function(d){
    alert("post");
       });
      });

In the php file right now I am simply doing `print_r($_POST);` but the post array is empty. Can some one please help me out. I think that some of us just don't understand ajax correctly. I thought I did but I am not able to get it to work.

Thank you.

Comment: `data:'cost=' +cost` should be `data:{cost: cost}` - otherwise *you* would have to care about properly encoding the value. You should also use `var cost = ..` instead of `cost = ..` to avoid creating globals

Comment: I made the above changes but I am still getting an empty array printed out so the data must not be being posted?

Comment: Try adding content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: where would i do ^^ that at?

Answer (score 1):

Use this
`data:{cost: cost}`
for sending the data.

Use this code:

```
$(document).on('click','#chkEndAccDate',function(){
cost = $('#total_cost').val(); 
$.post("http://sandbox.phareconsulting.com/complete_order.php",
{cost: cost},function(d){
});
});
```

Comment: I changed to that but it is still not working for some reason?

Comment: -1 since this does not solve the OP's problem. No matter what kind of invalid data `cost` contains - he'd at least receive an empty value, but not no POST data at all.

Comment: I did try that code above but I am still getting an empty array print out?

Comment: put alert(); in code and check if that function excutes or not.

Comment: I put an alert() before and after the $.ajax call, the before alert() fires but the after alert() doesn't fire.

Comment: I did this
 $(document).on('click','#chkEndAccDate',function(){
cost = $('#total_cost').val(); 
$.post("http://sandbox.phareconsulting.com/complete_order.php",
{cost: cost},function(d){
 alert("post");
});
});
but alert never fires

Comment: this mean that address it not correct please check name of php file. there may be case sensitive mistake.

Comment: and why the address has ";" in end get rid of that

Comment: Code looks like this
 $(document).on('click','#chkEndAccDate',function(){
        cost = $('#total_cost').val(); 
$.post("http://www.sandbox.phareconsulting.com/complete_order.php",
{cost: cost},function(d){
 alert("post");
});
});

The ; is being added when I paste the code in this box, the URL is copied from the address bar directly

Comment: both of function are working fine with {cost:cost} , i think either file doesnt exist, or you have no access to it, or wrong address / file name.

Answer (score 1):

This should be proper syntax:

```
data: "{'cost':'" + cost+ "'}"
```

Comment: **NO, just NO.** If he wanted JSON payload this would be invalid due to the single quotes. But since he wants normal POST data he needs to pass an urlencoded string or better an object like I suggested in my comment on the question.

Comment: I did change my code to use data:{cost: cost} and used var to avoid a global but on the page where it should be posted to I am still only getting Array() on my print_r($_POST) I don't really understand why the info is not being posted.

Answer (score 1):

s.d and Thiefmaster have already written the correct syntax, however, it may be a good idea to change the name of your variable so as to avoid confusion.

```
var totalCost = $('#total_cost').val();
```

Then use:

```
data: {cost : totalCost}
```

Comment: You also may want to check that the post variable in the php script matches the name you send in the data array. i.e. `$_POST['cost']`.

Comment: Dolchio print_r() will get all data in it. and changing cost to totalCost will never solve problem since jquery dont got confused by name xd

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea to use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to send ajax forms this will by itself grab the data and send it to the form action url.
This plugin also gives you functions that control the sending process . This is an example :

```
    var bar = $('#progressBar');
    var percent = $('#percent');
    var status = $('#status');
    $('#form-id').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            //validate the data 
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
           // draw a progress bar during ajax request
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            bar.width("100%");
            percent.html("100%");

        }
    });
```

Html for the progress bar :

```
    <div id="progress">
      <div id="bar"></div >
      <div id="percent">0%</div >
    </div>
```

css :

```
    #progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
    #bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
    #percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
```